# Select query returned empty result for my indian language

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table like below

[image]

https://photos.app.goo.gl/MWuakdf1daibihEHA

When I use

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dict 
 WHERE malayalam_definition = '$_value'
```

it returned empty row but if I use

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dict 
 WHERE english_word = '$_value'
```

I get values.

I use `SET NAMES utf8` still no luck.

I used utf8mb4 character set and utf8mb4_general_ci collation

Edit: First I created database with `utf8mb4_general_ci` collation and created table with same collation. Then I import csv file with

```
load data local infile '/mnt/c/Users/justi/Desktop/enml/enml.csv' 
into table dict 
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
fields terminated by '\t' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

php file

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "newuser";
$dbpass = "password";
$dbname = "dict3";

//Connect to MySQL Server
$c = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$quer = "SET NAMES utf8mb4";
mysqli_query($c, $quer);

$wpm = $_GET['wpm'];

$query="SELECT * FROM dict WHERE malayalam_definition = '$wpm'";

$qry_result = mysqli_query($c, $query) or die(mysqli_error($c));
if(mysqli_affected_rows($c)>0) {
  echo "done";
} else {
  echo "no";
}


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_result)) {


   echo $row['english_word']."<br />";
   echo $row['part_of_speech']."<br />";
   echo $row['malayalam_definition']."<br />";

}


?>
```

```
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| # id   | english_word   | part_of_speech | malayalam_definition            |
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| 174569 | .net           | n              | പുത്തന്‍ കമ്പ്യൂട്ടര്‍ സാങ്കേതികത ഭാഷ      |
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| 116102 | A bad patch    | n              | കുഴപ്പം പിടിച്ച സമയം               |
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
| 219752 | a bag of bones | phr            | വളരെയതികം മെലിഞ്ഞ വ്യക്തി അഥവാ മൃഗം |
+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
```

I use id as primary key.

Comment: the image is not working

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @DhananjaiPai image link added

Comment: @RaymondNijland You mean I need to provide more details? I added it. If any more needed please tell me.

Comment: I think my font not giving result in array too, `if(in_array($wpm, $row))` not giving result. It's related to php?

Comment: No, My font works with php. I tested. but `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_result)) { if(in_array($wpm, $row)) { echo "found"; break; } else { echo "Not found"; break; } }` after `SELECT malayamam_definition from dict;` gives not found

Comment: Some help please

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is Unclear, abandoned, and re-asked by the OP here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54616867/2943403

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of `$_value` you're trying to find in this code block?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dict 
 WHERE malayalam_definition = '$_value'
```

If the value does not match any values in the `malayalam_definition` column then there will really be no result.

Try debugging by checking if the values in `malayalam_definition` column can really be read by your query, just by selecting all the values from the `malayalam_definition` column:

`SELECT malayamam_definition from dict;`

If values are returned, try to copy one value from it and assign it to your `$_value` and try to query again your first query

````
/*replace $copiedValueFromTheReturnedValues with your copied value from the ```malayalam_definition``` column's returned values */
$_value = $copiedValueFromTheReturnedValues;

SELECT * from dict WHERE malayalam_definition = '$_value';
````

and try to debug from here.

#### EDIT

Please note that character set should be `utf8` and `utf8_unicode_ci` collation.

I think your while loop should be configured too. Add `MYSQLI_ASSOC` parameter inside your `mysqli_fetch_array()` to get an associative array rows and index them by table column name:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_result, MYSQLI_ASOC)) {


   echo $row['english_word']."<br />";
   echo $row['part_of_speech']."<br />";
   echo $row['malayalam_definition']."<br />";

}
```

After editing the charset, collation and while loop, this query of yours should work now. :)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dict 
 WHERE malayalam_definition = '$_value'
```

#### EDITED to answer your question:

> Is it correct usage while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_result)) { if(in_array($wpm, $row)) { echo "found"; break; } else { echo "Not found"; break; } }

To correct the code, should be:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  if($wpm === $row['malayalam_definition']) {
    echo "found";
    break;
  } else {
    echo "Not found";
    break;
  }
}
```

What I did is I added `MYSQLI_ASSOC` as parameter for your mysqli_fetch_array(). I also replaced your line `if(in_array($wpm, $row))` to `if($wpm === $row['malayalam_definition'])` since you're iterating thru each row. $wpm should be compared to each row's 'malayalam_definition' value.

Hope this helps. Let me know what problem you encountered. :)

Comment: `$_value` do present in malayalam_ definition

Comment: I edited my answer and added about the table and database char set. Kindly upvote if this helps. Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you sure about `CHARACTER SET utf8_unicode_ci` and not `CHARACTER SET utf8` and in first approach using `SELECT malayamam_definition from dict;` I tried `if(in_array($wpm, $row)) {
  echo "found";
  break;
} else {
  echo "Not found";
  break;
}` it returned `not found`

Comment: but `echo $row['malayalam_definition']; break;` after `SELECT malayamam_definition from dict;` gives result

Comment: Sorry my bad. Edited charset to be utf8 with utf8_unicode_ci collation. Thanks

Comment: Okey, any fix for my problem?

Comment: `print_r` giving `Array ( [0] => പുത്തന്‍ കമ്പ്യൂട്ടര്‍ സാങ്കേതികത ഭാഷ [malayalam_definition] => പുത്തന്‍ കമ്പ്യൂട്ടര്‍ സാങ്കേതികത ഭാഷ ) Array ( [0] => കുഴപ്പം പിടിച്ച സമയം [malayalam_definition] => കുഴപ്പം പിടിച്ച സമയം ) Array ( [0] => വളരെയതികം മെലിഞ്ഞ വ്യക്തി അഥവാ മൃഗം [malayalam_definition] => വളരെയതികം മെലിഞ്ഞ വ്യക്തി അഥവാ മൃഗം )`

Comment: In your code snippet ```
$qry_result = mysqli_query($c, $query) or die(mysqli_error($c));
if(mysqli_affected_rows($c)>0) {
  echo "done";
} else {
  echo "no";
}``` what's the result, is it "done" now?

Comment: It's `done`. I think it related to php. my font not work with `if(in_array($wpm, $row))`

Comment: I checked, array works with my custom code in my language

Comment: I edited my answer. I think the problem is also in the printing of the output. Kindly upvote my answer if it helped you. Thanks! :)

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Is it correct usage `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_result)) {
   
if(in_array($wpm, $row)) {
  echo "found";
  break;
} else {
  echo "Not found";
  break;
}

}`

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array() needs another param to identify whether it should be associative or numeric. So usage should be mysqi_fetch_array($qry_result, MYSQLI_NUM).

Comment: In your case you should use MYSQLI_ASSOC to get an associative array result so that you can index your results by column name.

Comment: @Khtty Please let me know if adding ```MYSQLI_ASSOC``` to your ```mysqli_fetch_array()``` function worked. Feel free to upvote. Thanks! :)

Comment: You asked result of `$qry_result = mysqli_query($c, $query) or die(mysqli_error($c)); if(mysqli_affected_rows($c)>0) { echo "done"; } else { echo "no"; }` Its `no` for `$query="SELECT * FROM dict WHERE malayalam_definition = '$wpm'";` I said `done` for `SELECT malayamam_definition from dict;`

Comment: Added my answer to your question. I hope this solves your problem now. :)

Comment: I get `not found` when using `SELECT malayamam_definition from dict;` and a blank page when using `SELECT * FROM dict WHERE malayalam_definition = '$wpm'"`